# Message says downloading wine-unity3d-installer (N/A MiB) appears, does not go away

Tags: wine, downloads, zenity, pipelight

A zenity message saying "downloading wine-unity3d-installer (N/A MiB)" will sometimes appear while I am doing something and just show a flashing download bar forever. 
I can force close it but a few minutes later it will just reopen. It just keeps doing this until I close it and it never finishes the process. The goal is to get this message to stop opening.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: what version of Ubuntu you're running? What the output to `sudo apt-get upgrade` is?  Please [edit] your question and add this information...